# How to form borders around links and text?

Tags: html, css

i am fairly new in coding and need some help. Currently i am trying to form a border around my texts and photo. But somehow I can't do it. It should roughly look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/16RvF.jpg. On the top parts photos and on the bottom ones text.

And my code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
<style>
img {
    border: 5px solid black;
}   
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/770467680012890112/kSz1jtnn.jpg" alt="Coca Cola"
<a href="coca-cola.com">Coca Cola</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Like this, i can only put a border around the logo.

I know how to text, link (`<p> <a href>`) but I don't know how to but a proper border around these. This is like 'here is my homework for you' but i really need help!

Comment: This is a handy starting point that should help you answer this question (and the others that will likely, rapidly follow it as you learn): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a class to store your border to cut down on  code.

```
.borders {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then assign that class to everything that you want to have a border:

```
<img class="borders" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/7704676800128901/kSz1jtnn.jpg"
```

As for the text you can add some padding to the top and bottom to increase the white space:

```
h2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set border for your logo like this:

in the css typing code like this.

```
img{
    border: 1px solid black;
   }
```

good luck

Answer (score -1):

Just like you have border around image using this style:

```
img {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

you can have border around almost any element like similar styles like:

```
p {
    border: 5px solid black;
}  

a {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Really? Do i just have to play with their heights and width to get the borders like in the example ?

Comment: You asked for borders we responded with borders. and YES, you can play with the heights and widths of p tag and a tag.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you!! i didn't think only playing would be enough.